# Car makes a "winding down" noise when I put in the clutch

Tags: noise, clutch

I am about to buy a '96 Saturn SC from someone, and he is letting me test drive it for a few days before I decide to buy or not. I took it in to a mechanic today who tested it out, found a few repairs that needed to be done, but nothing major. After getting it back from the mechanic I noticed a low pitched noise every time I put in the clutch to shift. It sounds like something is spinning at high revs then slowing down.

Is this something I should be concerned with? The mechanic took the car for a test drive and didn't mention anything about it, but I'm certain the noise did not start until after I got it back from the mechanic.

The car has 133,000 miles, and I think it has the original clutch in it still. I will ask the owner when I see him on Monday. He is asking $1,900 for the car which I think is a good deal, it is in great condition except for a few minor things.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be the thrust bearing of the clutch that's worn down. It makes a whining noise when the clutch is disengaged and it reguires replacing the clutch and thrust bearing to solve this.

Comment: How critical of a problem is this? Should I not use this vehicle at all until it is repaired, or can I use it regularly for the next 2 months while I get the money for a new clutch?  Thank you.

Comment: The worst that could happen is a complete breakdown of the thrust bearing and you won't be able to disengage the clutch when that happens. I can't say when that will happen, sometimes the bearing lasts for months before finally giving up and sometimes it's a matter of days.

Comment: Thank you. So i can safely use the car but should keep it to a minimum until fixed... I can do that.

Comment: @MasterZ, it's also a possible negotiation point to get the asking price down.  If you're buying a car that's going to need work, it's reasonable to ask the seller to subsidize the fix.